# How to host QGIS threejs outputs?

Tags: qgis, three-js

Is there a free simple way to serve / host the .html files the awesome Qgis2threejs plug-in produces?

I have tried using Google Drive as shown [here](http://www.komku.org/2013/08/how-to-host-javascript-or-css-files-on-google-drive.html) and [here](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2881970?hl=en) without success. Also had same results using One Drive.
I tried putting the 2 folders (dat-gui and threejs) and the html file in Google Drive (and One Drive) but can't seem to make it recognize the html... it just opens them in a text editor format [like so.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMTVL.png)

Would like to be able to view them anywhere with web access like [this one](http://members.chello.at/~graser/Qgis2threejs/).

Would a weebly or other free web site / blog be able to do this?
QGIS Server?

Comment: This is about hosting a website/page not using a GIS, just the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Drive works for me:

1. Make sure that the folder is shared with the public
2. Access the website via `www.googledrive.com/host/[id-of-the-folder]`, e.g. http://www.googledrive.com/host/0Bwc-5JFVTnfIWUlXSklaQndTNGc

My folder actually contains two projects/html files. The second one is
http://www.googledrive.com/host/0Bwc-5JFVTnfIWUlXSklaQndTNGc/albertina.html as you can see here:

[image]

Note: Data from the city of Vienna - data.wien.gv.at

Note 2:

> Host web pages with Google Drive
>
> Announcement: This will be deprecated August 31, 2015
> On August 31, 2015, web hosting in Google Drive will be deprecated. You can continue to use this feature until August 31st, 2016, but after that, googledrive.com/host/ID will no longer work.

Comment: Got the Google Drive method to come correct finally. Screen shot outlining the files needed here: http://i.imgur.com/hY4jtQt.png                               and an example displaying Tesla's Gigafactory location here:   https://d547d636f91a1ea309ac246053c0643c3071cdee.googledrive.com/host/0B0ujPOzxeGqeSENCcUZUV1BYNTA/Tesla_site.html

Answer (score 4):

## Github pages

With Github, create a `username.github.io` repository. Then, for your other repositories, you can create a `gh-pages` branch. If you have an `index.html`, you'll be able to navigate to http://username.github.io/project-name to see your map live on the web. Github has information on doing this [here](https://pages.github.com/).

I did this last night, with a quick export from QGIS2Leaf just to show a friend what I was working on (disclaimer: very early draft!). Here is the [repository](https://github.com/alpha-beta-soup/nz-ufo-sightings), and the [Leaflet map](http://www.spatialparalysis.xyz/nz-ufo-sightings/#6/-41.520/174.218). Note that I have registered a domain name, but alpha-beta-soup.github.io and spatialparalysis.xyz are the same place, and this is totally optional. If you haven't used git/Github before, there will be a slight learning curve, but there are plenty of online tutorials, and Github's own introductions are nice and gentle.

Comment: Nice map @alpha-beta-soup! Can I suggest you remove the geocoding information, as we GIS people are interested in that, but nobody else is =). Also, lat/lon is rarely interesting to normal people.

Comment: @AlexLeith Yep, very early draft, half the information is missing too.

Comment: @alpha-beta-soup For info: qgis2leaf is no longer under development. Try qgis2web instead, which offers both Leaflet and OL3 output (it's a merge of qgis2leaf and qgis-ol3).

Comment: @TomChadwin, yes I noticed that a little while after I wrote this. It still worked for my simple use case, which was just to avoid having to write any HTML or JS to get a shareable slippy map. I've moved to Mapbox with GeoJSON now as it has matured.

Comment: Love that Leaflet map... will have to pursue this Github solution as time permits.

Answer (score 2):

Free, simple. Choose one.

Not free, but $1/month:

http://www.nosupportlinuxhosting.com/

Free but can be a bit of a pain to setup:
GitHub

You load your folder as a GIT Repository, and using RawGit.com you can display HTML files. Example:

Git Repo:
https://github.com/HeikkiVesanto/QGIS_Multi_Ring_Buffer/tree/master/help

Link to the HTML file in RawGit:
https://rawgit.com/HeikkiVesanto/QGIS_Multi_Ring_Buffer/master/help/index.html